# Finding records that are expired

Tags: sql

I have a table, two of the columns of which are :

```
___________________________________________________
|  CREATED_DATE (DATE TYPE)  |   TTL(MINS IN INT)  |
|____________________________|_____________________|
```

I am trying to find the records that have expired.

So far I got this:

```
SELECT CREATED_DATE, TTL, STR(TTL) as DIFF 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
    CREATED_DATE + interval  '30' minute 
        < CAST(sys_extract_utc(SYSTIMESTAMP) AS DATE)
;
```

The problem is : if I want to use TTL instead of the constant `'30'`, trying:

```
+ interval '30' minute
```

to:

```
+ interval TTL minute
```

or:

```
+ interval DIFF minute
```

does not work.

How do I use `TTL` (which is in minutes) and add that to the creation time to see if the data has expired ?

Additional points that might help narrow down the answer.

1. I am going to use the statement to purge finally(delete) instead of read(select). So I don't want multiple reads going on for records.
2. This statement goes into hibernate's execute function in Work class called within getSession().doWork.

Thanks !

Comment: You have tagged the question SQL Server, but SQL Server does not use this syntax.

Comment: Your RDBMS and version please.

Comment: Oracle, version 12.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can also use [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DATEADD(minute, ttl, created_date)
```

Comment: yeah i tried that, couldn't get it to execute in sql developer. So went to + interval style

Comment: @navderm: this should work regardless of the client... Just in case: sqldeveloper is usually used as an Oracle client, this answer is for sqlserver (that you tagged the question with).

Comment: alright, lemme try that with hibernate and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
+ TTL * interval '1' minute
```